# Python string strip

Tags: python, string, strip

I am trying to use strip() to remove the end of some HTML. The idea is to eventually build this into a loop, but for now I am just trying to figure out how to make this work:

```
httpKey=("<a href=\"http://www.uaf.edu/academics/degreeprograms/index.html>Degree Programs</a>")
httpKeyEnd=">"

#the number in the httpKey that the httpKey end is at
stripNumber=(httpKey.find(httpKeyEnd))
#This is where I am trying to strip the rest of the information that I do not need. 
httpKey.strip(httpKey.find(httpKeyEnd))
print (httpKey)
```

The end result being to print httpKey to screen with just:

> a href="http://www.uaf.edu/academics/degreeprograms/index.html

Comment: What is your end goal? Are you trying to extract the href? If so, your life will be made significantly easier by using an HTML parsing library like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: Yes, that is the goal. However this is a homework assignment that I am working on and can only use string operations.

Comment: Okay, next question: is it intentional that there is no closing quotation mark after the href, or is that a typo?

Comment: that is intentional, I was trying to make the httpKey a string for right now. I guess I could have wrote httpKey=str("<a href="http://www.uaf.edu/academics/degreeprograms/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case this will work:

```
>>> httpKey=("<a href=\"http://www.uaf.edu/academics/degreeprograms/index.html>Degree Programs</a>")
>>> httpKey[1:httpKey.index('>')]
'a href="http://www.uaf.edu/academics/degreeprograms/index.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` will return the index where a string is found (a number), and `strip` removes characters *from the ends of a string*; it doesn't remove "everything from that point forward".

You want to use string slicing instead:

```
>>> s = 'hello there: world!'
>>> s.index(':')
11
>>> s[s.index(':')+1:]
' world!'
```

If you just want to find out what the link is, use a library like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> doc = bs('<a href="http://www.uaf.edu/academics/degreeprograms/index.html">Degree Programs</a>')
>>> for link in doc.find_all('a'):
...     print(link.get('href'))
...
http://www.uaf.edu/academics/degreeprograms/index.html
```

Comment: So that will Slice everything before, I need everything before character 63 and nothing after.